# Can i change the gutter from right to left?

Tags: grid, sass, susy-compass

I just want to know if i can change the gutter direction from the right to the left side.

Normally SUSY puts a "margin-right" to each column. But i want it to change to "margin-left". So it is easier to support IE8, for example:

```
.RR_grid-cont {
    @include container;
    > .RR_col {
        @include span-columns(1);
        &:first-child {
            @include omega;
        }
    }
}
```

So IE8 supports ":first-child" and the grid is fine in this crumpy Browser.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't built into Susy 1.x, but it's super-simple in Susy 2 - which is nearing the end of alpha development. You could probably trick Susy 1 into doing what you want with a creative use of `$from-direction` and `omega` — or download the Susy code and make a few minor tweaks yourself.